# Static array of structs with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, struct, static, numa

We have an array of structs like this one:

```
struct allocation
{
  size_t alloc_size_;

  char* alloc_memory_;
};

static struct allocation allocations[] =
  {{1024, NULL},{2048, NULL},};
```

later on in `main()` it's members `alloc_memory_` are initialized using `numa_alloc_onnode()`.

So the question: is `alloc_memory_` also static and where they are located (heap, stack) ? If they are not static then how to make them static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alloc_memory_` member of array `allocations` are static, but the memory the pointed to are not necessarily static.

In your case, since you allocated them with `numa_alloc_onnode` in `main`, this means they pointed to dynamic storage.

If you really want static storage too, you can define the memory before the structure:

```
static char buffer1[1024];
static char buffer2[2048];

static struct allocation allocations[] = 
{ {1024, buffer1}, {2048, buffer2} };
```

Comment: Ok thanks. In this case I would need a macro that would generate code type `static char bufferN[SIZE];`. Consider that `static struct allocation allocations[]` above is initialized as `static struct allocation allocations[] = ALLOCATIONS;`, where `ALLOCATIONS` is defined at compile time by user like `-D'ALLOCATIONS={ {1024, buffer1}, {2048, buffer2} }'` So the macro would have to parse `{ {1024, buffer1}, {2048, buffer2} }` and generate code: `static char buffer1[1024]; static char buffer2[2048];`. Could you please point me to such a macro? Thanks

Comment: I suggest not passing code through macros, you could pass the size of the buffer though, static `char buffer[N};` and `-DN=1024`